# Object not found in R keeps showing

Tags: r

When running this code I get this error message:
"Error in View : object 'filtered_tg' not found"

```
data("ToothGrowth")
View(ToothGrowth)
filtered_tg <- filter(ToothGrowth,dose==0.5)
View(filtered_tg)
```

Comment: What happens if you highlight `filtered_tg` and click control enter? Do you have `dplyr` loaded?

Comment: Did you load `library(dplyr)`?

Comment: The object `filtered_tg` does not exist. You are using `filter`, and i assume you want to use the one from `dplyr`. Did you load it with `library(dplyr)`?

Comment: You should have got another error `Error in filter(ToothGrowth, dose == 0.5) : object 'dose' not found` before the last error as `filter` by default will be using `stats::filter`

Comment: I forgot to load dplyr, thank you all! Im starting to learn this language :)

Answer (score 0):

```
# Make changes as below, you have to load dplyr library:::

data("ToothGrowth")
View(ToothGrowth)
library(tidyverse)
library(dplyr)
filtered_tg <- filter(ToothGrowth,dose==0.5)
View(filtered_tg)
```